# JavaFX Android-style navigation drawer with always visible buttons

Tags: java, javafx

Have you guys seen Windows 10 navigation drawer? It always shows the buttons (icons) but it requires to press on "hamburger" to see the text of the buttons. Is there a way to implement this behavior using JavaFX or some sort of libraries?

And also would be great to have a solution that stretches/squeezes the main content view. I've been trying to find something like this but met no luck doing so. Please, help me out with this! Appreciate any help

Comment: What about https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix ?